# Swift regular expression for 1 or more letters from list (vowels)

Tags: regex, swift

I'm writing a function to determine if a first name is valid. One step that it requires is at least 1 vowel in the string. I have tried this in the sandbox:

```
let firstName = "David"
// must have 1 or more vowels
let REGEX = "[aeiou]"
let check = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS %@", REGEX).evaluateWithObject(firstName)
```

When I run [aeiou] through an online tools it suggest the expression is valid for 1 or more vowels. So I wonder if this has to do with the "SELF CONTAINS %@" portion of code? I could not find an alternatives. I wonder if the SELF CONTAINS is restricted to one as it returns true for firstName = "a" but not "aa" or "David". Can someone advise?

Comment: You do realize that first names (or names) do not require to have a vowel? Or even any Latin character?

Comment: As far as I can see you haven't used any `quantifier`. `[aeiou]` will match **only one** character. To match multiple characters use `+` or `*`.

Comment: Also, there are vowels outside of the `[aieou]` range. Don't boss around your users.

Comment: To the people downvoting: This is a technically valid question. It has everything - the OP's intention, his current attempt, an error description. Downvote stuff that violates the form, don't downvote stuff just because you disagree with it on the content level.

Comment: agree. why not let people enter whatever they want?

Comment: @noob Can you clarify where the + or * go in the expression? I have tried in various locations and my sandbox still returns false.

Comment: @JanGreve Yes, I understand. When you have 10,000 profiles to review each day you need to automate some and reduce the amount that need manual interaction and stop people using, aaa etc.

Comment: As you were trying to match `aa` too, but you used only `[aeiou]`. This will match only `a`. To match `aa` you should say `[aeiou]+`. `+` means **one or many**. Now it will match `aa`, `aaa`, `aei` and so on.

Comment: @noob  If I take the code I originally posted and add a + where you suggested it still returns false. Can you try in your sandbox for Swift and confirm?

Comment: Sorry ! Am not a Swift programmer. I was helping you out with the regex part. Anyways does it returns false for `aa` ?

Comment: @noob, it's working for "aa" now so the + is correct but not for "David". So works for all vowels but not for more or 1 mixed with consonants

Comment: I have made this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gH5mZ4/1). Test it according to your naming rules and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the vowels and see if the name contains it. You should also create a success variable that checks to see if the name has a vowel. If it does, set the variable to true. It should look something like this:

```
let firstName = "David"
var containsVowel = false
let vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
for vowel in vowels {
    if containsVowel == false {
        if firstName.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(vowel) != nil {
            containsVowel = true
        }
    }
}
if containsVowel == true {
   //The name contains a vowel!
}
```

Comment: That's much easier achieved by replacing all vovels with the empty string and comparing string lengths before and after.

Comment: That is also a possible solution. However, I feel that this is simple, easy, and efficient.

Comment: At least `break` out of the loop when the first vowel is found. :) Also, `if booleanExpression == true` is an antipattern. Just do `if booleanExpression`.

Comment: Good idea. I will add that.